# Android emulator crash when start. HVF error: HV_ERROR

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, macos-big-sur

**Running the emulator on MacBook Air 2017 (Version 11.4 Beta)**

The idea logs of emulator :

Emulator: /Users/gaurav12/Android_SDK/emulator/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_2_API_30
Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
Emulator: cannot add library /Users/gaurav12/Android_SDK/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
Emulator: HVF error: HV_ERROR
Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument
Emulator: Failed to open the hax module
Emulator: No accelerator found.
Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HAX: Operation not supported by device
Emulator: added library /Users/gaurav12/Android_SDK/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
Emulator: cannot add library /Users/gaurav12/Android_SDK/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed
[image]Emulator: added library /Users/gaurav12/Android_SDK/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib
2021-04-26 14:53:28,526 [ 187258]   WARN - n.process.BaseOSProcessHandler - Process hasn't generated any output for a long time.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Navigate to folder containing qemu binary (e.g. `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64`)
2. Create file `entitlements.xml` with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>com.apple.security.hypervisor</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
3. Make sure you have XCode command line tools installed

   sudo xcode-select --install
4. Resign qemu binary:

   `codesign -s - --entitlements entitlements.xml --force ./qemu-system-x86_64`

***References:***

- https://www.arthurkoziel.com/qemu-on-macos-big-sur/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/ltp77a/anyone_using_qemu_for_linux_on_macos_big_sur/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/kdhgni/qemu_hvf_support_for_mac_os_x_bug_sur_hv_error/

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me. But there was just one more step to be done.
After running the give command in terminal there was an error which was to install command line tools for Xcode. So I installed it and retried the give command, it worked!
The command line tools for Xcode can be downloaded from here manually,
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Thanks @GauravPandit! I update the answer accordingly with this additional info.